# Font Awesome Icons won't print in IE11

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer, printing, font-awesome

The project we are working on is an Angular Web App. I am trying to print a list of content which is using FontAwesome icons for checkboxes and several other things. When I call `$window.print()` the preview shows correctly for IE11, Firefox, and Chrome. The page prints correctly (with icons) in Firefox and Chrome but not IE. We are printing from a new window but I do not think this would effect things since the icons load correctly in the new window before the print dialog comes up.

#### TL;DR

In IE the page prints with the correct styles but all the Font Awesome icons are missing. What could be causing this?

#### Relevant info

Font awesome is loaded (icons show on page before print).

I am trying to style this:

```
<span class="fake-checkbox checked">
    <div class="checkbox-selection-mark"></div>
</span>
```

with this rule (other rules excluded for brevity):

```
<style>
   .fake-checkbox.checked::before {
      font-family: FontAwesome; 
      content: "\f00c";
    }
</style>
```

it should look like this [image: Checklist Item]

I have included this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually works with this when u add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But since u have already included this and its still not working then please try adding the following to the start of the font-awesome.css file (before the @font-family call):

```
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|woff)$"> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" </FilesMatch>
```

Firefox (and, to a lesser extent, Chrome and IE) has an issue where it fails to download the font and so doesn't display any of the icons correctly.

A very easy fix has been identified in a number of locations, cdnjs/cdnjs#755 being one of them.

Comment: I do not believe this to be the problem. The font is correctly downloaded and viewed throughout the application. The only problem is with __print__ when all the icons do not show on the printed document (or pdf). However, they display correctly before and after the print on the web page so the font must have been downloaded correctly, right? Or am I missing something in your answer?